# In Wordpress: How do I get Page Template “page ID” to match “URL ID”

Tags: php, wordpress

1. I am new to PHP in general, so I’m not entirely sure what syntax to write.
2. I want to get the URL from the top browser (which will change when I click Next or Previous) example: (where the number after - # is the ID)

   - /gallery-1/, /gallery-2/, /gallery-3/,
3. Based on the Page URL I want to: Get the matching "page content" which is in it’s own directory file and titled  (where the number after - # is the ID)

   - page-gallery/gallery-1.php
   - page-gallery/gallery-2.php
4. If the URL [ID#] && Filename[ID#] == the same/Match, I want to 
   display template name filename[#].With an exception of null for error (Else: Error).

   - get_template_part( 'page-gallery/gallery', '{MATCHING-ID#}' );

Wordpress has the following features  that I know of (but don't know how to apply):

- **get page uri** (top-level-page/sub-page/current-page) where current-page is what I am trying to get + The ID. So I don't just want the current-page I want the current-page-[#].

- **wp_parse_url** (string $url) , is another feature that Wordpress has which may be helpful for breaking and splitting the url, but I'm not sure how to tell it to get the /current-page-# and if I'd have to compile an array to manually tell Wordpress of all the gallery-pages the site contains.

-**Pagination** - could be what I am attempting to do, where instead of breaking the gallery into multiple pages containing it all into a single page and using something like   but the pages I have are very long in general and I would have to merge all my separate files back into one.

-**Basename** - in relation to getting filename directories that I might have to use basename. Not sure how to do this but imagine it would follow the same pattern as URL and getting/splitting the ID that I need.

My current code is:

```
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
//if URL-[ID#] && Template[#] == 
//Then Display Template[#] that == URL [ID#] else, error.
// <-- Not sure how to write this, 
 //and if I need an array of my template_parts.                    
                get_template_part( 'page-gallery/gallery', '[Same # as URL]' );

            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>

            <?php getPrevNext(); ?>
```

I know this is something simple, but I don't know how to write the syntax for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.